# Drawing an arrow from a cell in a table contained in a node to an anchor of another node in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows, tikzmark

I have a tikz picture where I would like draw an arrow from a cell in a table contained in a node to an anchor of another node: (the arrow is added using Microsoft Paint)

[image]

I attempted to draw the arrow using `tikzmark`, which, as far as I know, works perfectly outside a `tikzpicture`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font = \ttfamily]
  \node (s) {
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      ptr & \tikzmark{s ptr} \\
      \hline
      len & 5 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  };

  \node [right = of s.north east] (content north west) {};
  \node [below right] (content) at (content north west) {
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      "hello" \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  };

  \draw [->] (s ptr) -- (content.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

only to be greeted with a puzzling error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.12       ptr & \tikzmark{s ptr} \\
```

Unclear what to do, I changed `\tikzmark` to `\tikzmarknode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font = \ttfamily]
  \node (s) {
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      ptr & \tikzmarknode{s ptr}{} \\
      \hline
      len & 5 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  };

  \node [right = of s.north east] (content north west) {};
  \node [below right] (content) at (content north west) {
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      "hello" \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  };

  \draw [->] (s ptr) -- (content.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which eliminated the error.  However, compiling the code several times, the arrow keeped moving among strange places, and finally converged to:

[image]

which is undesirable.

Currently, I work around this issue by hard-coding the coordinate via `(s.north east) - (10pt, 10pt)`.  Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With use of the `matrix` libraries is simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.append style = {minimum size=1.5em,
                            inner sep=1mm,  outer sep=0mm,
                            font=\sffamily}
                        ]   
\node (m) [matrix of nodes,
           nodes in empty cells, 
           nodes= {anchor=center},
           column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           draw, 
           inner sep=0pt
           ]
{
ptr     &   \\
length  & 5 \\
};
\draw   (m.west) -- (m.east)
        (m-1-2.north -| m-2-1.east) -- (m-2-2.south west);
\node [draw, right = of m-1-2.east] (n) {"hello"};
%
\draw [-Straight Barb] (m-1-2.center) -- (n);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** there is no way to add lines with features if `\hline` and vertical lines known from tables. However, it is possible to do *semi automatic*, meaning that you not draw them separately, however, you need to determine columns width with `minimum width` of cells in any column:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.append style = {draw, minimum size=1.5em,
                            inner sep=1mm,  outer sep=0mm,
                            font=\sffamily}
                        ]
\node (m) [matrix of nodes,
           nodes in empty cells,
           nodes= {anchor=center},
           column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           column 1/.append style = {nodes={minimum width=4em}}, % width of the wides cell in column 2
           column 2/.append style = {nodes={minimum width=2em}}, % with of the widest cell in column 2
           draw,
           inner sep=0pt
           ]
{
ptr     &   \\
length  & 5 \\
};
\node [draw, right = of m-1-2.east] (n) {"hello"};
%
\draw [-Straight Barb] (m-1-2.center) -- (n);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Similar solution also propose @leandriis  in his comment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `matrix` suggestion!  Is there a way to automate drawing the separation lines of the table for more cells?

Comment: @L.F., as far as i know, no.

Comment: @L.F.: You could try the following variant: `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0mm,font=\sffamily}]   
\node (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells, nodes= {anchor=center, draw},column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1.2cm}},]
{ptr     &   \\ length  & 5 \\ };
\node [draw, right = of m-1-2.east] (n) {"hello"};
\draw [-Straight Barb] (m-1-2.center) -- (n);
 \end{tikzpicture}`. I however had to fix the width of teh first column with this approach.

Comment: @L.F., one way is to determine columns width by minimum width of nodes in each column and than add to nodes option draw. So this is only *semiautomatic` ... I will to answer add this asap.